# dell poweredge r900 hard drive max limit

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012, dell-poweredge

Hey all I am in the market to buy a home server and ive been looking at different configurations and found the R900 having the best bang for the buck. However it concerns me that it states on dells website for this model that it only supports up to 5tb of hd space.

My question is: how possible is it to purchase pcie sata cards and use those instead of the onboard sata connectors?

I will be running vmware esxi and windows server 2012.

**UPDATE**

Turns out that its better to use the onboard SATA since it has its own dedicated RAID controller than trying to get a pcie card working for that.

Comment: If Dell says the configuration isn't supported, it probably isn't. Dell "server" type machines are quite narrow, there isn't much space for regular expansion cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dell R900 is a quad-socket RAM and CPU-optimized server platform. The internal disk place is limited because it's intended to be connected to some form of shared-storage.

- PCI-X is defunct.
- This is not a server you'd want in your home.
- 5TB internal storage: There isn't much space for disk inside the chassis.
- Yes, this can be connected to an external storage enclosure (DAS).
- No, this is not a good bang-for-the-buck.